# Zabbix intergration with CloudWatch-No data on Zabbix server LLD

Tags: amazon-web-services, zabbix

I followed this guide:https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch

Added dummy host with 127.0.0.1 IP, it's located on Zabbix server itself

```
./awsLLD.py -a "default" -r "eu-west-1" -q "SNSTopics" -c 'topic'
{
"data": [
{
"{#AWS_REGION}": "eu-west-1",
"{#AWS_ACCOUNT}": "default",
"{#TOPIC_INAME}": "",
"{#TOPIC_NAME}": "topic"
}
]
}
```

AWS-CloudWatch-display name of zabbix-host

localhost:zabbix server

default-AWS account

```
./cron.SNS.sh "topic" "AWS-CloudWatch" "localhost" "default" "eu-west-1"
{'host': 'AWS-CloudWatch', 'value': 2.0, 'key': u'SNS.NumberOfMessagesPublished.Sum["default","eu-west-1","topic"]', 'clock': 1532180160}
{'host': 'AWS-CloudWatch', 'value': 2.0, 'key': u'SNS.NumberOfNotificationsDelivered.Sum["default","eu-west-1","topic"]', 'clock': 1532180160}
{'host': 'AWS-CloudWatch', 'value': 0.0, 'key': u'SNS.NumberOfNotificationsFailed.Average["default","eu-west-1","topic"]', 'clock': 1532180160}
Count: 3
```

Monitoring-Latest Data-empty

Imported example SNS template and attached it to host

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am i missing here, data are retrieved from Cloudwatch but didn't get any errors for transfered to Zabbix server

I tried Lambda template and it works without issues, Lambda template has no Discovery rules,so i presume that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working:

had to copy awsLLD.sh to  `/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts/`
after zabbix-service restart SNS data started to appear in Zabbix